# Ubuntu 15.10 wouldn't boot until I remove nomodeset in grub

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, nomodeset

Initially I wasn't able to boot from USB to install `Ubuntu 15.10`, therefore, I added `nomodeset` in `GRUB` and managed to installed Ubuntu.

Afterwards, I installed Nvidia drivers (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M 4GB GDDR5) by from the PPA, as instructed [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/08/ubuntu-nvidia-graphics-drivers-ppa-is-ready-for-action)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```

Everything worked smoothly until I rebooted and found that I can no more login. I can see the login screen but when I provide username and password, the screen refreshes and loads the same login screen with a beep.

Upon this, I rebooted and entered the grub menu by hitting `e` and observed that there is `nomodeset` still there. I removed this nomodeset and am now able to login. However, it only works for the current session and I manually have to remove `nomodeset` from grub menu everything I boot.

Is there some permanent fix to this please??

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/etc/grub.d` and `/etc/delault/grub`. You should find a place where the option is added. Once removed, run `update-grub`.